# Angular 9 rxjs - forkJoin returns array of Observables instead of array of values

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, observable, fork-join

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```
this.store.pipe(
  select(arr),
  switchMap(arr => {
    const data = arr.map(arrItem => this.dataService.getData(arrItem.id));
    return forkJoin(...data);
  }
  map(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  )
);
```

Somehow, in console.log I'm getting array of values only if arr.length = 1. If arr.length > 1, I'm getting array of Observables instead.

How is it possible? Am I misunderstanding forkJoin? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you make a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: What is the response type of `this.dataService.getData` method ? An `Observable` from an `HttpClient.get` request ?

Comment: @ThierryFalvo yes, exactly

Comment: @martin I'll make it if Thierry's answer won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If your service response is an `observable` and you want to retrieve an array of response at the end, you can do this :

```js
this.store.pipe(
  select(arr),
  switchMap(arr => from(arr)),
  mergeMap(arrItem => this.dataService.getData(arrItem.id), 2),  // max 2 concurrents requests here
  toArray()
).subscribe(datas => {
  // datas is an array of returned data from getData service
});
```

Note here second argument of `mergeMap` (= `2`), to specify maximum concurrent request.

`switchMap(arr => from(arr))` : from an array value, to a new observable with emitted values = each value of the array

`toArray()` : take all values emitted, and transform to one array

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm now trying to implement it to my code. Will update you when I'm done.